# Couldn't retrieve signature from database got this error java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat

Tags: java, arrays, itext

I am successfully stored user signatures into database. but, when I try to retrieve list of user signatures in a loop into pdf document, I got this java.io.IOException thrown at the line `Image signpr = Image.getInstance(userSign);`: as The byte array is not a recognized imageformat. Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Below is my code

```
PdfPTable userTable = new PdfPTable(1);
if (user.size() != 0) {

    userTable .setWidthPercentage(100.0f);
    userTable .setWidths(new float[] { 6.5f });

    for (int i = 0; i < user.size(); i++) {
        for (User e : user) {
            
            byte[] userSign = e.getuserSigns().getBytes(); 
            if(userSign!=null) {
                Image signpr = Image.getInstance(userSign); //sign
                signpr.scaleToFit(100,80);
                signpr.setAbsolutePosition(450, 80); 
                doc.add(signpr);
            }                           
            PdfPCell userName = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(e.getuserNames()));
            userName.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            userTable .addCell(userName);
            
            userName.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        }
    }
}
doc.add(userTable);
```

Comment: The error message suggests that whatever is in `userSign` doesn't represent an image (or uses an image format that the `Image` class doesn't support). Can you dump the first few bytes (like 10-20) and [edit] your question to include them? Then we could take a look if it looks like a common image format. Alternatively try to write it to a file and see if that opens in the image viewer of your choice.

Comment: Maybe Joachim guessed right. Could you also state at which line the IOException is thrown?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri Exception Thrown at this line ----> Image signpr = Image.getInstance(userSign);

Comment: Have you checked if the image type you are using is supported in iText? iText supports JPEG, JPEG2000, GIF, PNG, SVG, BMP, WMF, TIFF, CCITT and JBIG2 images
https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/which-image-types-are-supported-by-itext

Answer (score 0):

ALTER DATABASE your_db SET bytea_output TO 'escape';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).